# How to edit in plugin page in wordpress ??

Tags: wordpress

Once I'm in Wordpress and I go to the page "XYZ", and I go to "edit" I want to write something there to introduce the reading, the the text doesn't show, only the plug in shows up, why would this be? –

I just wanted to show you what I mean. So there I added text to introduce the reading below (plug in) but once I update and go to the page, the text is not there, only the plug in.

Here is my code on edit page:

This is the reading plugin .. /// text

[exercise] /// calling plugin

Comment: Sounds like the plugin is not enabled. Anyway, this question is mor suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I doesn't get u sir